# Getting Docker container network to run on Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, docker, heroku

I am a Docker novice, but locally I can successfully run my container with: `docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --net example-net  -p 8080:8080 my/repo`

Typically I can just [push a container to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#getting-started) and it just works (which I thought was the whole idea of Docker; once you get it to run once it should run everywhere), but in this case the application doesn't load.

Presumably something about the above `docker run` is non-standard and the Heroku Docker environment isn't running my container in the same way my local environment is.

I don't know enough about Docker or Heroku to really debug further.

The underlying application is a Spring Boot web app and Heroku logs say `Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

Comment: "Presumably something about the above `docker run` is non-standard and the Heroku Docker environment isn't running my container in the same way my local environment is." Normally you wouldn't `docker run` at all with Heroku. How are you executing this command? Are you literally using `-p 8080:8080`?

Comment: You are right that I am fundamentally not understanding how Heroku handles Docker. But essentially I built the Docker container then `heroku container:push web` and `heroku container:release web`